# Acrobat Reader and second screen

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I try to use Acrobat Reader on a second screen.

If I open AR on the second screen and ask for fullscreen mode, AR open the fullscreen on the main screen. It is impossible to video project in fullscreen mode on the second screen.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and AR 9.4.2.

Any idea why ?

Comment: It is almost certainly a bug in _Adobe Reader_, and you should contact Adobe support about the issue.

Comment: Ok. I installed AR 11.0 with wine and it works perfectly.